# 'Associated' data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

For an ecommerce platform, we're looking to index products. Default fields are simple as: `name_en`, `name_de`, `name_fr`, `description`. But, price and stock are dependant on another value:

- `Product A`, for `webshop 1`, has `price = 1.99`, `stock = 10`, and fits under categories 1, 10, and 50.
- `Product A`, for `webshop 2`, has `price = 5.99`, `stock = 5`, and categories 9, 90, and 500.

I was thinking of nested objects, but is that even an option?

```
- name_en: Product A
- description_en: Product A description
- webshops: [{
    - key: webshop_id
      value: 1
    - key: price
      value: 1.99
    - key: stock
      value: 10
    - key: categories
      value: [1, 10, 50]
    },{
    - key: webshop_id
      value: 2
    - key: price
      value: 5.99
    - key: stock
      value: 5
    - key: categories
      value: [9, 90, 500]
    }
]
```

Is it easy querying like this? Can we easily get the entire document, with the values where `webshop.key.webshop_id.value = 1`, or `webshop.key.categories.value = 500`?

Is my thinking wrong, any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest as you did, but it will get difficult to update the price or stock of a product in a single webshop, because you'll have to reindex the whole `webshops` array. There are ways to around it, but that's convoluted.

Instead of having a nested structure, you can also denormalize the webshop part and simply include the `price`, `stock` and `categories` fields in the documents like this.

```
Document 1:
- name_en: Product A
- description_en: Product A description
- webshop_id: 1
- price: 1.99
- stock: 10
- categories: [1, 10, 50]

Document 2:
- name_en: Product A
- description_en: Product A description
- webshop_id: 2
- price: 5.99
- stock: 5
- categories: [9, 90, 500]
```

Then in your queries you can simply add a constraint for `webshop = 1` or `webshop = 2` (or both) depending on which webshop you're querying against. It's also much easier to update the price, stock and categories of a product in a specific shop, all you have to do is update the corresponding document.

This means that your product data (name, description, etc) will be copied once per webshop but it's not a big deal usually (pretty common in the NoSQL world), you just have to update 2 documents instead of a single, but `_bulk` will help there. At least, when you add new webshops, you don't need to reindex all your data (!!!) and you change the prices, stocks in one webshop without interfering with the others.

Comment: Right-o, more denormalization. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the parent/child relationship capability.

You must define two document types: product and webshop

In the mapping, you must define the relationship like that : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html

```
{
  "webshop" : {
    "_parent" : {
      "type" : "product"
    }
  }
}
```

Like that you can index all the products in the product type. Then you can index all the webshop details related to the product.

You can use the query/filters to retrieve the webshop details related to a product.

Like that you have real different documents that can be queried separately.